# Correct way to use DownloadManager and Content Provider for Android Q (API 29) and above?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-download-manager, android-11, scoped-storage

The problem with my code is, it is downloading the file and it is showing in the gallery having path like
=> "/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename.jpg"

But when I click on the finished download notification it opens a file with a URI => "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/7123"

and it is of 0kb.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

       //Setting title of request
       request.setTitle(fileName);
       request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
       request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
       String mimeType =
               
 MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
       request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);

       if (!Utils.checkNullOrblank(mimeType))
           request.setMimeType(mimeType);

         
       
 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            {
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            }else
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(filepath, fileName);

            downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
           contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.TITLE,fileName);
           contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
           contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);

           contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

           // Insert into the database
            ContentResolver database = context.getContentResolver();
            uri.setValue(database.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues));
      }
```

what am i doing wrong? how to do this process in a correct way?

Comment: `uri.setValue` ??? I see no uri instance. Where does it come from?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` If there is a catch you are still executing the following code. Why? Isnt it better to stop then? And how do you inform the user about that catch?

Answer (score 0):

1. With `ContentValues` you only registers in the database(inner) but does not insert the downloaded object itself. After you have configured content value use bitmap compress to save your object itself. `uri = database.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues))`, `uri = your file uri`
2. Use only:

```java
contentValues.put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.TITLE,fileName);
```

without `contentValues.put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)`.

After saving with bitmap compress

```java
contentValues.clear();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);                            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName + ".ext");
```

then

```java
uri.update(insert, values, null, null);
```